# Question on mutual singularity and absolute continuity of complex measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was presented these two somewhat similar questions from Folland's real analysis (second edition) dealing with complex measures and their mutual singularity and absolute continuity. They are 3.19 and 3.20 as follows:
[image]
they mean total variation by the absolute value.
I am really stuck on these although they may seem simple to a lot of people but I am sorry I cannot figure it out
I would really appreciate the help.
Edit: In part a specifically I cannot figure out how to carry out the changing of separating sets from the original measures to their total variations
Edit: definitions for exercise 19. Mutual singularity of two measures $ \nu \perp \mu $ means existence of a partition of disjoint sets into two sets of X such that on the first $ \nu $ is zero while on the other $ \mu $ is zero. The symbol << is absolute continuity of measures of course

Comment: For "20", you just need to use the fact that $\nu$ is finite and aditive. Just pick up a set of negative measure $B$ and calculate $\nu(X) = \nu(B^c) + \nu(B) < |\nu|(B^c) + |\nu|(B) = |\nu|(X)$.

Comment: @AndréCaldas thank you very much but $ \nu $ is complex so who said you could even take such a negative measure set B?

Comment: @AndréCaldas I also cannot see how your comment solves it to show that they are equal measures everywhere

Comment: Notice that $\nu(X) \geq 0$! The inequality still stands... :-)

Comment: @AndréCaldas I think I understand your trick now showing they are equal is only problematic for negative and complex measurable sets now your very nice solution helps for negative sets, how about complex sets?

Comment: It is just the same! Comparison with $<$ was made only for real numbers!

Comment: @AndréCaldas Got it thanks! Any help you can give me for problem 19?

Comment: For me, those in "19" are just the definitions. Why don't you write the definitions in your post?

Comment: @AndréCaldas Added the definitions for #19 can you please assist now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question 19

For a complex measure $\gamma$ and a set $B$, notice that $\gamma(A) = 0$ for every measurable $A \subset B$ iff $\lvert\gamma\rvert(B) = 0$. And this happens iff $\lvert\gamma\rvert(A) = 0$ for every measurable $A \subset B$.

From the above, $\nu \perp \mu$ iff $\lvert\nu\rvert \perp \lvert\mu\rvert$.

And,
\begin{align*}
\lvert\nu\rvert \ll \lambda
&\Leftrightarrow
(\lambda(B) = 0 \Rightarrow \lvert\nu\rvert(B) = 0)
\\
&\Leftrightarrow
(\lambda(B) = 0 \Rightarrow \forall A \subset B \text{ measurable},\,\lvert\nu\rvert(A) = 0)
\\
&\Leftrightarrow
(\lambda(B) = 0 \Rightarrow \forall A \subset B \text{ measurable},\,\nu(A) = 0)
\\
&\Leftrightarrow
\nu \ll \lambda
\end{align*}

### Question 20

Notice that $\nu(X) = \lvert\nu\rvert(X)$ is real.
Suppose there is a $B \subset X$ such that $\nu(B) \not \geq 0$ (it might be complex).
Then,
\begin{equation*}
\nu(X)
= \nu(B) + \nu(B^c)
<
\lvert\nu(B)\rvert + \lvert\nu(B^c)\rvert
\leq
\lvert\nu\rvert(B) + \lvert\nu\rvert(B^c)
=
\lvert\nu\rvert(X).
\end{equation*}
A contradiction, since we assume $\nu(X) = \lvert\nu\rvert(X)$.

---

**PS:** Please, do not post an image of the math. Write it down in latex.